# Uncaught Error: Module name "electron" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: angularjs, electron, electron-builder

I am facing this error:

Uncaught Error: Module name "electron" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

```
$scope.sendWhatsapp = function (report) {

let url = 'https://wa.me/91' + report.patient_phone_no + '?text=Hi, Your report is ready. Please visit the laboratory to collect it.'
console.log(typeof window.require);

if (typeof window.require === 'function') {
    const shell = window.require('electron')

    shell.openExternal(url);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just set a global variable and access this in the Angular component

```
**main.js**
app.whenReady().then(() => {`
let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({`
    webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        contextIsolation: true
    },
    width:640,
    height: 480,
    resizable: false
})
... rest of code
**preload.js**
const { contextBridge, shell} = require('electron')
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
'electron',
{
    shell: shell
})
```